# Display images by category (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an app that displays images based on their categories, with the category being an attribute of the image like so:

```
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "caption"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  t.string   "i_file_name"
  t.string   "i_content_type"
  t.integer  "i_file_size"
  t.datetime "i_updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "category"
end
```

I want the index.html.erb page to have several links/buttons that render all of the pictures from each category. I was trying to get the index page to just display the images from one category like so:

```
<% @images.each do |post| %>
  <% if post.category == "Portfolios" %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag post.i.url(:medium)), image_path(post) %>
    <%= post.caption %>
    <%= post.category %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But nothing appears when I do this, including the post.category, even though I had assigned some images to the "Portfolios" category. This also isn't really what I want either.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe put an else, and output the actual category, to debug in your view... You may be better off with a relationship for the categories. It will normalize your database for that attribute, and allow you to do things like Category.first.images...

Comment: @BradWerth how would I start going about doing that?

Comment: The debugging is simple erb, so I'm assuming you're talking about the relationship... Not sure where you're at, but http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association should be a good starting point. The field would basically become a drop-down, populated with category names (or whatever), and the value would be the category id to use as an fkey.  Hopefully that makes sense. (Even though it doesn't really answer your original question)

Answer (score 0):

This is separate from your question, but would indirectly resolve it: I would recommend making a `Category` model/table and relating to it from your `Image` model.  You'd create a `categories` table, which would have a `name` column, then replace the `categories` column on your `images` table with a `category_id` integer foreign key column (just like how you defined your relationship between Images and Users).  You'd define the relationship like so:

```
# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

Then, if you wanted all images in a specific category, you'd simply do this: `Category.find_by_name('Portfolios').images`.  Or to make your list of categories that link to lists of images in each category, you might use a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).  On your categories index, you'd iterate over each category and generate a link to its nested images. The whole thing might look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
#...
resources :categories, only: [:index] do
  resources :images, only: [:index]
end
#...

# controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.order(name: :asc)
  end
end

# controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category

  # NOTE: nested beneath /categories/:category_id/
  def index
    @images = @category.images
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    end
end

# app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, [category, :images] %>
<% end %>

# app/views/images/index.html.erb
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag(image.i.url(:medium))), image_path(image) %>
  <%= post.caption %>
  <%= post.category %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted to keep your current schema, you'd want to use `where` for efficiency, which will ultimately add a WHERE clause on to your SQL query.  I don't know what's setting your @images variable in your template, but I imagine it's something like `Image.all`.  Instead, you should set it to just the images you want.  In this case, you'd set it to something like this: `@images = Image.where(category: 'Portfolios')`, then you'd just iterate over them in your template like so:

```
<% @images.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag post.i.url(:medium)), image_path(post) %>
  <%= post.caption %>
  <%= post.category %>
<% end %>
```

Note that there is no longer a conditional.  In your example, you were querying all images, which causes Rails to instantiate an object for each Image, even the ones not in the Portfolios category that you don't need.  Instead, you should query just the records you need with `where` instead of filtering them as you are iterating over them in your template.